# Collating an RTL "book" in InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, publishing

I've been working on a siddur, or [Jewish](http://Judaism.stackexchange.com) prayerbook, in InDesign. However, all of my training has been in the "document", creation within InDesign, which is to say, I can make perfectly decent layouts, but I don't know how to string everything together.

I did attempt to compile a "book" with the files which I already had, however the result was that I lost all of my RTL formatting and needed to completely redo it. 
How do I compile an RTL "book" in InDesign?

Comment: My apologies if this is a dupe, I'm new to this SE site.

Comment: Have you Googled "How to create a book in InDesign"?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, I have, however I when I followed the instructions I found, I discovered the above problem.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I believe you need the multilingual version of InDesign to support RTL publications.

Comment: @Scott, I have that version

Comment: Then I suspect you may have missed an option when creating the book file. I don't have the ME version so there's little testing I can do to verify this.